# Check if a sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose that a sequence $(x_n )$ in $R$ satisfies
$x_{n+1} = 1 −\sqrt{1 − x_n}$

for all n ∈ N. Show that $(x_n )$ converges. To what does it converge? Does
$(x_{
n+1}/
x_{n})
$
converge?

I have solved the first and found that except for $x_1=1$, all other initial values makes the sequence converge to $0$. For the second part, (if the ratio converges) : if the initial value is 1, the ratio for sure converges to $1$ as all terms are $1$. If the initial value is $0$, it doesn't as none of the terms of the ratios are defined. For the intermediate values I am not sure how to prove that the ratio converges to some number( which my intuition tells me to be 1)? As I can't use ratios of limit result as the limits are $0$ $$$$ Constraint: Can't use taylor series as the book didn't reach there yet.

Comment: For fraction convergence, may be, will be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713482/lim-of-fraca-n1a-n

Comment: @zkutch: I don't think that helps since the OP is interested in the fraction in the case that $\lim_n x_n = 0$.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani. Probably you are right, because I still have not definite answer for $0$, but, may be,  little info, that limit can be on $[-1,1]$, which is there, help to arise some ideas.

Comment: That -1 and 1 bound seems to be directly coming from the ratio test, otherwise the sequence will diverge. So basically it is same as saying, for each case it will be different when the limit tends to 0.

Comment: Let $x_n=1-d_n$ (because $d_n\to 0$ if $x_n\to 1$). Then $d_{n+1}=\sqrt {d_n}\,.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence converges to some limit $z$, it must satisfy
$$
z = 1-\sqrt{1-z} \Rightarrow (1-z)^2 = 1-z \Leftrightarrow z=0 \vee z=1.
$$
So, if the sequence converges, if must converge to either $0$ or $1$. In fact, the sequence will converge to $0$, unless $x_0=1$, in which case it will converge to 1.

Now, if $x_0<1$,

$$
\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lim \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x_n}}{x_n}=\lim\frac{x_n}{x_n (1+\sqrt{1-x_n})}=\frac 12.
$$

If $x_0=1$, $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{1}{1}=1$.

If $x_0 = 0$, the sequence $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is not even defined.

Comment: minor formatting typo: I think you mean $\lim\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ instead of $\displaystyle\lim_{x_{n+1}}x_n$.

Comment: You need handle the case of $x_0 =0$ case separately, I believe.

Comment: @Bhaswat, yes but in that case the sequence $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is not even defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $0<a\le x_n\le b<1$ we have:

$$0<x_{n+1}={1-\sqrt{1-x_n}}={x_n\over 1+\sqrt{1-x_n}}\le {x_n\over 1+\sqrt{1-b}}$$